# elementary question about probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X \sim N(0,1)$, then what is the joint probability distribution of $(Y=X+1,X)$?

An attempt: $f(y,x)=f(x+1,x)=f(x+1|x)f(x)=f(x)$... which doesnt make sense to me, since the distribution is now $N(0,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis looks correct. Since $Y = (X+1,X)$, the value of $Y$ is completely determined by $X$ which is normally distributed like you said. The value of $X+1$ in $Y$ is simply 1 plus the value of the normally distributed $X$. So the distribution is basically just a normal distributed, represented in a 2-dimensional fashion where one coordinate has an added +1.

Comment: $(Y,X) \sim N((1,0),(1,1; 1,1))$